# Linux C IPv6 raw socket - tell socket NOT to assign a flow label

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ipv6

I was trying to send something using an IPv6 raw socket. For some reason, I need IPv6 flow label to be empty. Linux seems to be assigning random flow label when it is not set by the user.

What I found is `IPV6_FLOWLABEL_MGR` and `IPV6_FLOWINFO_SEND`. I was able to assign a label myself using `IPV6_FLOWLABEL_MGR` with a `in6_flowlabel_req` by setting `IPV6_FLOWINFO_SEND` to true.

However, I can't find the option to disable the automatic assign behavior. I tried setting the label to 0 manually - but Linux assigned a new label to it when user set the label to 0.

Am I missing something?

Comment: By an "empty" flow label, do you mean one with all bits 0?

Comment: And when you say "not set by the user" do you mean "specified as zero by the user"?

Comment: @john-bollinger not set by the user mean the user did not specify anything, and yes, by empty I mean all bits are 0.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the user cannot *fail* to set a flow label on an IPv6 socket when they `connect()` or `bind()` it.  It is part of `struct sockaddr_in6` (member `sin6_flowinfo`), an instance of which must be provided to both those interfaces.  Is your problem perhaps that you do not initialize this member?  Or how else should I interpret "did not specify anything"?

Comment: I did initialize it. For "did not specify anything" I mean user did not use `IPV6_FLOWLABEL_MGR` to set a label.

Comment: "_I need IPv6 flow label to be empty._" Why?

Comment: I'm trying the implement MikroTik's EoIPv6 tunnel. Somehow MikroTik seems to be discarding incoming EoIPv6 packet with a non-zero flow label.

Comment: I managed to get it work by setting `IPV6_HDRINCL` and build the IPv6 packet including header myself.

Answer (score 4):

See the [sysctl](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt):

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/auto_flowlabels - INTEGER
    Automatically generate flow labels based on a flow hash of the
    packet. This allows intermediate devices, such as routers, to
    identify packet flows for mechanisms like Equal Cost Multipath
    Routing (see RFC 6438).
    0: automatic flow labels are completely disabled
    1: automatic flow labels are enabled by default, they can be
       disabled on a per socket basis using the IPV6_AUTOFLOWLABEL
       socket option
    2: automatic flow labels are allowed, they may be enabled on a
       per socket basis using the IPV6_AUTOFLOWLABEL socket option
    3: automatic flow labels are enabled and enforced, they cannot
       be disabled by the socket option
    Default: 1
```